# Does $a(a^{-1} \bmod b) + b(b^{-1} \bmod a) < ab + 2$ hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here we assume $(a,b) = 1$ and $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ are canonical (e.g.  $0 < a^{-1} < b)$.

Counter example or proof are appreciated!

Comment: So you're assuming $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime (positive) integers here?

Comment: Yes! (has been edited)

Comment: Hint: the $x$ and $y$ in $xa+yb=1$ (which are guaranteed by the definition of GCD) can both be taken to be in 'canonical' range $|x|\lt b$, $|y|\lt a$.

Comment: Almost the right hint, but you need actual positive representatives. That is, the definition of "canonical" did not allow negative numbers.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's why it's a hint. :-) Finding positive representatives from that is a quick next step...

Comment: It just confused me to use the word "canonical" two different ways, but of course I get it.

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $x=a(a^{-1} \bmod b) + b(b^{-1} \bmod a) $.
Then $x\equiv 1\pmod{ab}$ and $x<2ab$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: If you use the Euclidean algorithm, you get integers $m,n$ with $ma+nb=1$. One will be positive, one will be negative. Without loss of generality, take $m<0<n$. Then how do you get your canonical $a^{-1}$ from $m$ and your canonical $b^{-1}$ from $n$?

By the way, now that you're done, it seems that the answer will *always* be $ab+1$. That follows from both suggested proofs.